# How to predict compositional data in R

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I have two sets of compositional variables, one measured on Device 1, another on Device 2. I would like to develop a model to convert the data of `Device1` to `Device2`. For this I wanted to use the compositions package of R. The construction of the model seems to work fine, but I cannot predict the compositions of old data (`OldData`) using this model. How can I get a predicted composition for each sample in the `OldData` data frame? I've included a reproducible example of my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#loading library
library(compositions)

#Generate data
Device1 <- data.frame(
x = runif(50, min = 0.2, max = 0.6), 
y = runif(50, min = 0.2, max = 0.5),   
z = runif(50, min = 0.1, max = 0.7))  
Device2 <- data.frame(
x = runif(50, min = 0.2, max = 0.6), 
y = runif(50, min = 0.2, max = 0.5),   
z = runif(50, min = 0.1, max = 0.7))  

#Make data compositional
dataset1 <- acomp(dataset1)
dataset2 <- acomp(dataset2)

#Model
mod <- lm(ilr(Y)~ilr(X), data=list(X=Device1, Y=Device2))
summary(mod)

#Generate data to be predicted
OldData <- data.frame(
x = runif(100, min = 0.2, max = 0.6), 
y = runif(100, min = 0.2, max = 0.5),   
z = runif(100, min = 0.1, max = 0.7))  

#Prediction of new compositions
ilrInv(predict(mod, X=OldData[1:100]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that predict requires a data.frame with columns having the exact name of the objects mentioned in the formula within the lm fit. Compositional regression models make use of "collective names" (X) for the whole composition instead of identifying each variable in the formula. To trick predict to work in this case, we need then to create a data.frame with a column of the appropriate name containing the whole composition! There are several ways to get that, for instance:

```
# create a fake data.frame with the right number of rows
newdt = data.frame(placeholder=0*OldData$x)
# append a single column containing the whole composition
newdt$X = OldData
# now we can indeed call predict:
ilrInv(predict(mod, newdata=newdt))
```